# Trouble With Python Code

Tags: python

I am taking the introduction to computer science class at Udacity and for one of the assignments I must write code that will take all the links from a webpage. Here is the code

```
def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('<a href=')
    while True:
        if start_link == -1:
            x, y = None, 0
            return x, y
            break
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote
```

When I run samples, it seems to work, but when I submit my code, I get the result that my submission did not terminate. What does this mean? What is the issue with my code?

Comment: It means that your program never stopped running (within some amount of time).

Comment: So how do I prevent that?

Comment: You are stuck inside of while True loop, start_link is never -1 in your case, so you need another way of ending that loop probably

Comment: Your loop will run forever if `start_link != -1`.

Comment: the whle loop will run only once if start_link will be -1, and if not it will run forever but will do nothing
The break statement do nothing.

Comment: This loop really seems useless anyways.

Comment: Yeah right now the loop is useless. Because `start_link` never changes during the while loop, if it is not `-1` when the loop begins then the loop will carry on forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_next_target(page, start=0):
    """ function find link in part of page """
    start_link = page[start:].find('<a href=')
    if start_link == -1:
        x, y = None, None
        return x, y
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1:end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def find_all(page):
    """ function find all links"""
    length = len(page)
    current_position = 0  # we start with full page
    urls = []
    while current_position < length:
        # get url and set current_positon, so next we gonna search 
        # only part of page
        url, current_position = get_next_target(page, current_position)
        urls.append(url)
        if current_position is None:
            return urls
    return urls
```

But I would recommand use regular expressions - something like:

```
def find_all(page):
    import re
    return re.findall('<a href="(.+)"', page)
```

**Edit:**
But neither solution will detect links like:

```
<a  href="some/page">, or <a tilte="ti" href="some/page" >
```

for this you will need recreate the regular expression. It is the best option IMHO.